# Difference between run() realizations in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, try-catch, runnable

I tried to experiment with `threads`. The question is:

> What is the difference between `while nested in try/catch` and `try/catch nested in while`.

Here is the test:

```
    myThread.start("first");
    Thread.sleep(150);
    myThread.interrupt();

    myThread.start("second");
    Thread.sleep(250);
    myThread.interrupt();

    myThread.start("third");
    Thread.sleep(50);
    myThread.interrupt();

    myThread.start("forth");
    myThread.interrupt();

    myThread.start("fifth");
    Thread.sleep(1);
    myThread.interrupt();
```

I used two realisations of **Thread** class' `run` method to test console output.

**`first realization:`**

```
public void run() {
        while(!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);
                System.out.println(thread.getName());
                Thread.sleep(90);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

**`first output`**

```
first
first
second
second
second
second
second
second
third
third
third
forth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
fifth
.....`billion of 'fifth'`
fifth
```

This wasn't the output I wanted, so I changed my code a little and here is **`second realization:`**

```
public void run() {
        try {
            while(!thread.isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(0);
                System.out.println(thread.getName());
                Thread.sleep(90);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

**`second output:`**

```
first
first
second
second
second
third
fifth
```

And it's correct! I just swapped `while` and `try`. The output should be the same! Why so different?

Comment: when you `catch (InterruptedException e)` you must set the interrupted flag manually if you're testing for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930189/why-does-thread-sleep-clear-the-interrupted-flag

Comment: it seems my question was unspecified. Edited.